# Merge [android-sugarorm] and [sugarorm]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Should we merge [sugarorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sugarorm) and [android-sugarorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sugarorm)?

> Insanely easy way to work with Android databases.

---

So, it doesn't seem to have an *Android Version* and a *Non-Android Version*, which would mean it's appropriate to pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done: **[sugarorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sugarorm)** is the master tag, and [android-sugarorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sugarorm) has been merged into and made a synonym of the master tag. The tag name should match the name of the product.

If it's relevant that the asker is targeting the Android platform, then adding an [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag will serve that purpose adequately.